# Cómo traducir "scaled" en el contexto de las gráficas digitales

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Mucha gente utiliza *escalar* pare traducir *to scale* en el contexto de las gráficas digitales. A mi me parece una mala traducción ya que en el castellano *escalar* me hace pensar en *escalar una montaña.*  Me gustaría utilizar *redimensionar*, solo que los correctores de texto parecen no reconocer la palabra   *redimensionar*.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar a qué se refiere este término a todos aquellos que, como yo, desconocemos este vocabulario técnico?

Comment: SVG es el acrónimo de Scalable Vector Graphics. Es posible transformar la imagen SVG utilizando el atributo transform="scale(2, 2)". Esto redimensionaría la imagen x 2 a la alza tanto horizontalmente como verticalmente. Me gustaría traducir Scalable Vector Graphics con Graficos Vectoriales Redimensionables. Pero no sé si es correcto

Comment: *Engrandar/reducir*? No puedo pensar en una sola palabra que compendia ambas funciones. *[Re](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFxyLmQ)[dimensionar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DnCIBKL)* me suena bien.

Comment: Nunca habia pensado en esto, pero tienes razón, el uso de *escalar* como sinonimo de *redimensionar* no está recogido por la RAE, y tiene toda la pinta de ser un false friend que se ha acabado adoptando como traduccion real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un caso curioso, si buscamos el verbo [escalar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G6T25Xg%7CG6TYQPC), no existe ninguna acepción que se refiera a cambiar las dimensiones de algo.

Esto puede llevar a creer que solo se trata de un "false friend" que por alguna razón ha acabado siendo aceptada por la comunidad, pero no nos podemos olvidar de la palabra [escala](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G67txjD), cuya séptima acepción dice lo siguiente:

> 7. f. Tamaño o proporción en que se desarrolla un plan o idea.

Por lo tanto yo creo que el hecho de que aceptemos *escalar* como sinónimo de *redimensionar* sea una consecuencia tanto del false friend como de haber convertido el sustantivo *escala* en un verbo.

Comment: Bien visto. Actualmente se usa mucho en frases del tipo _este negocio escala muy bien, pues una vez desarrollado el software es solo cuestión de venderlo como churros_. No sabía que fuera false friend.

Answer (score 2):

En muchos casos de ausencia de términos equivalentes, lo mejor es traducir el concepto: *"Scale this drawing."* se traduciría como *"Aplica un factor de escala a ésta gráfica."*, que me parece no tiene ambigüedades. Sin embargo, en el caso específico del formato SVG podría decirse *"Gráficos Vectoriales Ajustables"*, donde *ajustar* se consideraría como aplicable a todas las características, no solamente a las dimensiones, lo cual sería incluso más preciso. En éste otro ejemplo: "Ajusta la imagen a una hoja tamaño carta", se transmite una idea similar sin confusiones (por el contexto).